# Need to fixate current of motor connected to a battery

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, constant-current

I have a gadget which includes a small 80mAh DC vibration motor connected to a CR2032 3V coin battery. The motor needs to keep running as long as the battery has juice, but instead of having it run at full speed and slow down gradually as the battery drains I prefer to have it running at constant speed more or less as long as the battery can provide enough power.

What would be the simplest (cheapest) way to implement such a solution in a small form factor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "80mAh motor" sounds rather unusual.  Are you sure that's what you meant?  A datasheet for the motor would be useful, but I'll assume you want to maintain 3V across it.

For a constant speed you need a constant voltage across the motor. Therefore you want a device that can convert varying lower voltages from the cell to a fixed higher voltage across the motor.

The solution is a boost converter. These are available in tiny packages around which you would design the necessary passives according to the datasheet recommendations.  Alternatively if you want a ready-made solution, you can also buy small boost converter modules containing the IC and necessary passive elements.

Note that you shouldn't do this in any situation where it's important to have warning of impending depletion of the cell or battery.

Comment: Here's the spec:
http://vibration-motor.com/products/pancake-vibrator-motors/coin-motor-C1034B018F.html

How small can the boost converter get? From what I saw online it's in the ~1cm^3 range, I need something that'll be 10mm*10mm*3mm at most

Comment: Boost ICs can be extremely small. The inductor tends to be the largest supporting passive component. Designing an appropriate circuit from scratch in that form factor is possible. If you aren't prepared to do this... well. Shopping questions are not allowed so all I will say is that an ebay search for 'tiny boost converter' is a logical step, and that not all components on such modules are mandatory - bulky connectors, as a hypothetical example.

Comment: I'll do some sniffing in this direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

battery voltage will drop when it is discharging 
so you can do a little bit of a trick you should buy at least a 5-volt battery and connect it to a 3.3 regulator so if the battery voltage drops you still get your fixed 3.3 volts and you will run at maximum speed